# Remove numbers from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Let us say I have a numpy array of numbers (eg: integers). I want to drop the number `k` wherever it happens in the sequence. Currently I am writing a for loop for this which seems to be a overkill. Is there a straight forward way to do it? In general, what if I have one more than one number to be dropped.

Comment: Can't you simply use `a[a != <some number>]` ?

Comment: Yes, I can do that. Does it guarantee that the order is preserved?

Comment: Yea it should return the elements in the same order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `A` to the input array and `B` to be the array containing the  numbers to be removed, you can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to get a mask of matches of `B` in `A` and then use an inverted version of the mask to map `A` and get the desired output. Here's how the implementation would look like -

```
A[~np.in1d(A,B).reshape(A.shape)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [14]: A
Out[14]: array([3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1])
In [15]: B
Out[15]: array([2, 4])

In [16]: A[~np.in1d(A,B).reshape(A.shape)]
Out[16]: array([3, 1, 3, 3, 1])
```

For a 2D input array case, you would get a 1D array as output, like so -

```
In [21]: A
Out[21]: 
array([[3, 3, 3, 4, 0, 4],
       [2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3],
       [1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1],
       [0, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1]])

In [22]: B
Out[22]: array([2, 4])

In [23]: A[~np.in1d(A,B).reshape(A.shape)]
Out[23]: array([3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to check for a single scalar value. In numpy, when you compare a vector to a scalar value, you get back an array of `True/False` values, where each element indicates the result of the comparison of the scalar value to the element. Example -

```
In [15]: a = np.random.randint(10,100, (100,))

In [16]: a
Out[16]:
array([63, 19, 84, 89, 89, 76, 18, 16, 57, 65, 25, 31, 17, 20, 25, 14, 27,
       70, 79, 87, 82, 59, 50, 86, 20, 42, 81, 58, 32, 23, 68, 12, 19, 98,
       11, 90, 76, 55, 40, 66, 83, 64, 46, 65, 94, 64, 91, 89, 18, 44, 59,
       52, 51, 22, 32, 94, 88, 38, 31, 91, 47, 76, 62, 43, 89, 41, 76, 81,
       50, 53, 76, 97, 49, 91, 39, 81, 52, 94, 21, 77, 94, 96, 28, 57, 38,
       10, 55, 57, 55, 41, 15, 14, 91, 69, 80, 43, 83, 31, 21, 76])

In [17]: a != 15
Out[17]:
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
       False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Then you can use this `bool` array, to index your original array, which would return the values back where the indexing array has `True` , This is part of [`Boolean array indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) . Example -

```
In [18]: a[a != 15]
Out[18]:
array([63, 19, 84, 89, 89, 76, 18, 16, 57, 65, 25, 31, 17, 20, 25, 14, 27,
       70, 79, 87, 82, 59, 50, 86, 20, 42, 81, 58, 32, 23, 68, 12, 19, 98,
       11, 90, 76, 55, 40, 66, 83, 64, 46, 65, 94, 64, 91, 89, 18, 44, 59,
       52, 51, 22, 32, 94, 88, 38, 31, 91, 47, 76, 62, 43, 89, 41, 76, 81,
       50, 53, 76, 97, 49, 91, 39, 81, 52, 94, 21, 77, 94, 96, 28, 57, 38,
       10, 55, 57, 55, 41, 14, 91, 69, 80, 43, 83, 31, 21, 76])
```